# How can I get the position of node from end in linked list

Tags: java

In single linked list such as (11 12 13 14 15). If I want to get position of node "15", it should be 0 and 14 should be 1 and so on. How can I do this? The method for this is public in positionOflast()

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330664/i-dont-understand-how-lastindexof-method-works-in-java

Comment: Why would element with value 15 be index 0? That means that you know the length of the linked list before you start iterating.

Comment: I need  to start from the end of list for example. for example. in this list (11 12 15 14 15) returning the first 15 from end not from the beginning.

Comment: some friends say that I should us backward recursion.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`descendingIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator()) method and loop n number of times where n is the index.